# Calculate Employee's Average Project Closing Time

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Powerbi, I currently have the following data:

Employee | Project Type | Project ID | Hours spent on Project ID | Closed Date

Additionally, I have a slicer that allows me to filter this data by year (Date Hierarchy from Data). I would like to add another column that displays the Average amount of Hours Billed to the Project Type without considering Employee - allowing me to compare Employee's Project Type hours average to Team's Project Type hours average.

I created another table using DAX that included the columns listed below, including Date to filter by year, but excluded Employee. But when I created the relationship between the table's Date it just replicated Employee Average. Without the Date relationship, the table visual gives me and error.

Average Hours Billed to the Project Type (MEASURE - distinct counting Project IDs of Project Type):

```
Avg Template =
  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
      VALUES(Activities[Time_Spent]),
      DISTINCTCOUNT(Activities[Template_ID])
    )
  )
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your dax code for the measure "Average Hours Billed to the Project Type".

Comment: Just did! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to:

```
Avg Template project =
  CALCULATE(
    [Avg Template],
    ALLSELECTED('EmployeeTable')
  )
```

Or:

```
Avg Template project =
  CALCULATE(
    [Avg Template],
    REMOVEFILTERS('EmployeeTable')
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am going to have to reassess. For some reason the DAX i provided is actually providing a count and not average. I will then try your suggestions and report back! Apologies for the confusion.